# How do you fix the Performance Dashboard datetime overfow error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance-monitoring

I'm a programmer/DBA by accident and we're running SQL Server 2005 with Performance Dashboard for basic monitoring.  The server has been up for a few weeks and now we can't drill into certain reports.  Is there any way to reset these reports without a complete reboot?

**edit:** I bet the error message would help.

I get this when I drill into the CPU graph:
Error: Difference of two datetime columns caused overflow at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are the errors your getting?

Have you tried re-running the dashboard set-up script?

One approach you could try is to close SSMS and then delete reports.xml from %userprofile%\Application Data\microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell which clears your custom report data I think - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/780bac33-663a-4532-a23c-fb10564cb328

Then make sure that it's the performance_dashboard_main that you open - the other reports are accessed from it.

Comment: It's not a custom report and I did try re-running the setup script.  I read somewhere there was a 24 day limit to some reports due to a int overflow when doing date math.  Now I can't find where I read it.

Comment: There's a fix for that error on this blog  which mentions the 24 day limit http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlrem/archive/2007/03/07/Performance-Dashboard-Reports-Now-Available.aspx

Answer (score 1):

go to system database >> msdb >> programmability >> Stored procedure >> usp_Main_GetSessionInfo

sum(convert(bigint, datediff(ms, login_time, getdate()))) - sum(convert(bigint,s.total_elapsed_time)) as idle_connection_time,

replace above by below

sum(convert(bigint, CAST ( DATEDIFF ( minute, login_time, getdate()) AS BIGINT)*60000 + DATEDIFF ( millisecond, DATEADD ( minute, DATEDIFF ( minute, login_time, getdate() ), login_time ),getdate() ))) - sum(convert(bigint, s.total_elapsed_time)) as idle_connection_time,

Comment: Prooflinks: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissk/archive/2008/06/19/performance-dashboard-error-difference-of-two-datetime-values-caused-an-overflow-at-runtime.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sachinp/archive/2008/08/11/sql-server-2005-performance-dashboard-difference-of-two-datetime-values-caused-an-overflow-at-runtime-error-message.aspx